# Unwanted Huge Space below <td>

Tags: html, css, epub

I'm making an e-book and `<figure>` & `<figcaption>` are being rendered as unknown tag in Sigil, so I used `<table>` for image and caption but it leaves a huge gap like in the picture below.

HTML

```
<table class="imgtable" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<tr>
  <td class="imgs" style="border: 1px solid black;"><img alt="2b - 69" src="../Images/2b_-_69.jpg" width="100%" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="caption">A 1795 photograph of some stalwarts under the famous banyan tree “…all sentiment…” and a mute witness to the growth of cricket in Calcutta.</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
    table.imgtable {
  width: 100% !important;
  margin-left: "auto" !important;
  margin-right: "auto" !important;
  text-align: "center" !important;
}
table.imgtable td.caption {
  padding-top: 7px !important;
  padding-bottom: 7px !important;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
  padding-right: 10px !important;
  border-right: 3px solid #262626 !important;
  border-top: 1px solid #262626 !important;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #262626 !important;
  border-left: 1px solid #262626 !important;
  font-family: "EB Garamond 08" !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 80% !important;
  background-color: white !important;
  border-radius: 3px !important;
  width:"auto" !important;  
}
table.imgtable td.imgs {
  padding-top: 7px !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
  width:100%;
}
img {
  width: "auto" !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Assuming that image doesn't have extra space at the bottom of it, since you're using tables instead of divs, try adding a height modifier to snap the height up, like <table height="0px" .../> and put the same into the <tr> tag. ...alternately you can add height:0px; into your style tag.

Comment: Can you post your link or create fiddle for better understanding your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing), set it to 0 for table.

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/8ka3d7ut/).

HTML

```
<table class="imgtable" style="border: 1px solid black;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="imgs" style="border: 1px solid black;">
          <img alt="2b - 69" src="../Images/2b_-_69.jpg" width="100%" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="caption">A 1795 photograph of some stalwarts under the famous banyan tree “…all sentiment…” and a mute witness to the growth of cricket in Calcutta.</td>
    </tr
</table>
```

CSS

```
table.imgtable {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-left: "auto" !important;
    margin-right: "auto" !important;
    text-align: "center" !important;
}

table.imgtable td.caption {
    padding-top: 7px !important;
    padding-bottom: 7px !important;
    padding-left: 1opx !important;
    padding-right: 10px !important;
    border-right: 3px solid #262626 !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #262626 !important;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #262626 !important;
    border-left: 1px solid #262626 !important;
    font-family: "EB Garamond 08" !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    font-size: 80% !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    width:"auto" !important;  
}

table.imgtable td.imgs {
    padding-top: 7px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    width:100%;
}

img {
    width: "auto" !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'block' function in CSS rather than using 'td' in html.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a table and avoid `!important` (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

```css
.figure {
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: "auto";
    margin-right: "auto";
    text-align: "center";
}

.figure .caption {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-right: 3px solid #262626;
    border-top: 1px solid #262626;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #262626;
    border-left: 1px solid #262626;
    font-family: "EB Garamond 08";
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 80% ;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width:"auto"; 
    margin-top:5px; /*Adjust this as desired*/
}

.figure img {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" >
  <div class="caption">A 1795 photograph of some stalwarts under the famous banyan tree “…all sentiment…” and a mute witness to the growth of cricket in Calcutta.</div>
</div>
```