# Table has huge space when is child of div flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to put an HTML table on the right side of a canvas and for some reason, it has huge spaces between rows.

I've tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069948/html-table-with-spaces)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159797/unwanted-huge-space-below-td) but none of them solved the problem.

Here's my current code:

```html
<html>

<body style="margin: 0px">
  <div style="display: flex">
    <canvas style="background-color: blue;"></canvas>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>hi</td>
          <td>l</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>lol</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1 - Set `align-items: flex-start` in `div` because the default value is `stretch`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

canvas {
  background-color: blue;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>hi</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lol</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### Solution 2 - Set `align-self: flex-start` in `table`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

canvas {
  background-color: blue;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-self: flex-start
}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>hi</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lol</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the table height to `min-content`

```html
<table style="height: min-content;"> ... </table>
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <canvas style="background-color: blue;"></canvas>
  <table style="height: min-content;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>hi</td>
        <td>l</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>lol</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a hacky solution